# Formula multipicklist exclusion

Tags: formula-field

I have a field that a consulting team recreated to capture multi-select picklist values.  The issue that when we are excluding one of the values, I seem to only capture the data of "one" value when only one is selected and nothing when the "excluded" field is included in the multipicklist.

Example:
I want to exclude "A" but creating the formula the way I have researched makes everything "NULL" if it's included in the picklist.  I want to simply and not have the "[]" display if it's the only option selected on the picklist.

```
IF(ISBLANK(MultiPicklist__c), "",
Record_ID__c&" "&
IF(OR(ISNULL(MultiPicklist__c), INCLUDES(MultiPicklist__c, "A")),"",

"["& 
IF(INCLUDES(MultiPicklist__c,"B"),"B,",NULL)& 
IF(INCLUDES(MultiPicklist__c,"C"),"C,",NULL)& 
IF(INCLUDES(MultiPicklist__c,"D"),"D,",NULL)& 
IF(INCLUDES(MultiPicklist__c,"E"),"E,",NULL)& 
IF(INCLUDES(MultiPicklist__c,"F"),"F",NULL)&
"]"))
```

I also tried this...

```
IF (ISBLANK(MultiPicklist__c), "", 
Record_ID__c&" "&IF(ISNULL(MultiPicklist__c),"", 

IF(INCLUDES(MultiPicklist__c,"A"),NULL, NULL)& 
"["& 
IF(INCLUDES(MultiPicklist__c,"B"),"B,",NULL)& 
IF(INCLUDES(MultiPicklist__c,"C"),"C,",NULL)& 
IF(INCLUDES(MultiPicklist__c,"D"),"D,",NULL)& 
IF(INCLUDES(MultiPicklist__c,"E"),"E,",NULL)& 
IF(INCLUDES(MultiPicklist__c,"F"),"F",NULL)&"]"))
```

I get what I am looking for but I cannot remove the "[""]" for "A".
Thoughts, please?

Updated Scenario:

```
IF (ISBLANK(MultiPicklist__c), "", 
Record_ID__c&" "&IF(AND(ISNULL(MultiPicklist__c),NOT(INCLUDES(MultiPicklist__c,"B")),NOT(INCLUDES(MultiPicklist__c,"C")),NOT(INCLUDES(MultiPicklist__c,"D")), NOT(INCLUDES(MultiPicklist__c,"E")), NOT(INCLUDES(MultiPicklist__c,"F"))),"", 
"["& 
IF(INCLUDES(ID_Type__c,"B"),"B,",NULL)& 
IF(INCLUDES(ID_Type__c,"C"),"C,",NULL)& 
IF(INCLUDES(ID_Type__c,"D"),"D,",NULL)& 
IF(INCLUDES(ID_Type__c,"E"),"E,",NULL)& 
IF(INCLUDES(ID_Type__c,"F"),"F",NULL)&"]"))
```

I got nothing, but still show the "[""]" when A is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula is written incorrectly based upon the objective you've stated. Formatting as below can help to make the logical sequence clear:

```
IF(ISBLANK(MultiPicklist__c), 
   "",
   Record ID__c&" "&
   IF(OR(ISNULL(MultiPicklist__c), INCLUDES(MultiPicklist__c, "A")),
      "",
     "["& 
       IF(INCLUDES(MultiPicklist__c,"B"),"B,",NULL)& 
       IF(INCLUDES(MultiPicklist__c,"C"),"C,",NULL)& 
       IF(INCLUDES(MultiPicklist__c,"D"),"D,",NULL)& 
       IF(INCLUDES(MultiPicklist__c,"E"),"E,",NULL)& 
       IF(INCLUDES(MultiPicklist__c,"F"),"F",NULL)&
       "]"))
```

The key issue here is the `OR` function. If the `OR` evaluates to `true`, your result will be the value of `Record ID__c`, a space, and then an empty string (`""`). Your bracketed list of letter codes are only included if the `OR` condition evaluates to `false`, meaning that `INCLUDES(MultiPicklist__c, "A")` must also evaluate to `false`. That's why you get a mostly blank result if the multi-select picklist includes this value.

You actually don't need the `OR` function at all, because you already checked whether `MultiPicklist__c` is blank at the top level of your logic.

I'm not sure there is an elegant way to suppress the brackets when the picklist is just "A", since the functions applicable to multi-select picklists are so few. One way to do it would be to replace `INCLUDES(MultiPicklist__c, "A")` with `AND(NOT(INCLUDES(MultiPicklist__c,"B")), [and so on for C-F])`. This will, of course, become unmanageable as your picklist grows, which would suggest moving to an Apex solution.

Comment: Which would be the best example?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I added the AND(NOT(INCLUDES(MultiPicklist__c, "B"), NOT(INCLUDES(MultiPicklist__c, "C"), NOT(INCLUDES(MultiPicklist__c, "C"), and so on, and I still see the "[""]"

Comment: What does your current formula look like?

Comment: I'll add it up top @david Reed

Comment: Remove `ISNULL(MultiPicklist__c)` from the `AND()`. You already do a null-check at the top level.

Comment: that was FREAKING awesome!!! I am putting you down for President as a "Write in" in 2020 or maybe a State Rep or Senator. :)

Comment: I'll settle for marking Accepted if you're good to go :)